# Convert multiple rows to new columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have following table:

```
[Field 1]           [Field _2]          [Field_3]
Mnemonic           Cow                               Duck
Last Updated    6/11/2018           6/13/2018
```

And I want to transpose it using SQL to the output below, eliminating the row of Field 1, Field 2, Field 3 and making Mnemonic and Last Updated the two new column headers:

```
            Mnemonic  Last Updated                      
            Cow       6/11/2018
            Duck      6/13/2018
```

Should I use a cross apply function, PIVOT, or another function?

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets, so the two values could appear in any order.  It is not clear how you determine which goes first.

Comment: Does your example include the full table?  It seems like there should be other fields (like a primary key) and something to tie the `Mnemonic` row to the `Last Updated` row, unless of course you really only have two rows, and dozens of columns...  Anyway, you haven't shared enough of what the real table looks like to make an intelligent recommendation.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: yes, PIVOT is good to achieve your requirement.